# Failed to compile with Gem5

Tags: compilation, gem5

I'm trying to compile gem5 on mac os.
I have solved 3 problem that faced until now, but i'm stopped at the last error.

The error says :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"PyTrafficGen::start(pybind11::object)", referenced from:
module_init(pybind11::module&) in lib.o.partial
"typeinfo for PyTrafficGen", referenced from:
pybind11::detail::type_caster_base::cast(PyTrafficGen const*, pybind11::return_value_policy, pybind11::handle) in lib.o.partial
pybind11::class_<PyTrafficGen, BaseTrafficGen, std::1::unique_ptr<PyTrafficGen, pybind11::nodelete> >::class<>(pybind11::handle, char const*) in lib.o.partial
pybind11::class<PyTrafficGen, BaseTrafficGen, std::__1::unique_ptr<PyTrafficGen, pybind11::nodelete> >::init_instance(pybind11::detail::instance*, void const*) in lib.o.partial
_ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZNS0_C1INSt3__110shared_ptrI7BaseGenEE12PyTrafficGenJyEJNS_4nameENS_9is_methodENS_7siblingEEEEMT0_FT_DpT1_EDpRKT2_EUlPS7_yE_S6_JSL_yEJS8_S9_SA_EEEvOSC_PFSB_SE_ESK_ENKUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_clESS in lib.o.partial
_ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZNS0_C1INSt3__110shared_ptrI7BaseGenEE12PyTrafficGenJyyyyyyhyEJNS_4nameENS_9is_methodENS_7siblingEEEEMT0_FT_DpT1_EDpRKT2_EUlPS7_yyyyyyhyE_S6_JSL_yyyyyyhyEJS8_S9_SA_EEEvOSC_PFSB_SE_ESK_ENKUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_clESS in lib.o.partial
_ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZNS0_C1INSt3__110shared_ptrI7BaseGenEE12PyTrafficGenJyyyyyyhyjjjjjjEJNS_4nameENS_9is_methodENS_7siblingEEEEMT0_FT_DpT1_EDpRKT2_EUlPS7_yyyyyyhyjjjjjjE_S6_JSL_yyyyyyhyjjjjjjEJS8_S9_SA_EEEvOSC_PFSB_SE_ESK_ENKUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_clESS in lib.o.partial
_ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZNS0_C1INSt3__110shared_ptrI7BaseGenEE12PyTrafficGenJyyyyyyhyjjjjjjjEJNS_4nameENS_9is_methodENS_7siblingEEEEMT0_FT_DpT1_EDpRKT2_EUlPS7_yyyyyyhyjjjjjjjE_S6_JSL_yyyyyyhyjjjjjjjEJS8_S9_SA_EEEvOSC_PFSB_SE_ESK_ENKUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_clESS in lib.o.partial
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

Mac os High Sierra 10.13.6

clang version:
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0

Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Any solution?

Comment: Hi Betal, please familiarize yourself with the code block markdown syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help which will greatly improve the readability of your post. Also always give the gem5 commit when reporting compilation problems. Consider also posting this on the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The changes in below link cause this error :

https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/11518/

You can revert changes in SConscript file at `“gem5/src/cpu/testesr/traffic-gen/SConscript”` and try co compile .

I could compile fine and run a spare benchmark with revert the changes in SConscript file like below :

```
    Import('*')


Source('base.cc')
Source('base_gen.cc')
Source('dram_gen.cc')
Source('dram_rot_gen.cc')
Source('exit_gen.cc')
Source('idle_gen.cc')
Source('linear_gen.cc')
Source('random_gen.cc')
Source('stream_gen.cc')

DebugFlag('TrafficGen')
SimObject('BaseTrafficGen.py')

#if env['USE_PYTHON']:
#   Source('pygen.cc', add_tags='python')
 #  SimObject('PyTrafficGen.py')

# Only build the traffic generator if we have support for protobuf as the
# tracing relies on it
if env['HAVE_PROTOBUF']:
   SimObject('TrafficGen.py')
   Source('trace_gen.cc')
   Source('traffic_gen.cc')
```

Hope works fine for everyone who face same error.

Cheers ,
Belal.